# Using Regex in a MultiThreaded Environment

Tags: c#, regex, multithreading

I have a constructor that uses several `Regex` objects which are `static readonly` in a class called `RegexLib` (mainly because this project uses a whole lot of `Regex` patterns that need to be used all over the place.

Upon the user adding some files to the application, this constructor gets called once for each file (run aynchronously across several threads). I've attached the relevant function that the constructor calls below.

```
private void GetSymbolsFromLines()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Lines.Length; i++)
    {
        string line = Lines[i];
        if (RegexLib.InstString.IsMatch(line))
        {
            int instString = i;
            int userdataString = 0;
            for (int j = i; j < Lines.Length; j++)
            {
                if (RegexLib.UserdataString.IsMatch(Lines[j]))
                {
                    userdataString = j;
                    break;
                }
                else if (Lines[j].Contains("userdata"))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (userdataString != 0)
            {
                _symbols.Add(new Symbol(RegexLib.InstString.Match(Lines[instString]), 
                    RegexLib.UserdataString.Match(Lines[userdataString])));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `Regex` objects are all fairly similar to these and have been tested using [Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/tester/).

```
    public static readonly Regex AliasFromUserdata = new Regex(@"text_alias=(?<AliasName>\w+).*?value=(?<AliasValue>(.*?))\^(?=(?:text_alias|\""))");
    public static readonly Regex UpdateFromUserdata = new Regex("FOX_VAR=.*?attr=(?<AttributeType>.+?)\\^(?<AttributePropertyString>.*?)\\^(?:(?=(?:FOX_VAR|END_FOXV)))");
```

For some reason, the use of `Regex` seems to cause some issues in this multithreaded environment and a dig into the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6h453d2h(v=vs.110).aspx) revealed that this could be because:

> However, result objects (Match and MatchCollection) returned by Regex should be used on a single thread.

So my question is, is there an easy way to use `Regex` accross mutliple threads whilst structuring them inside a library class for organisational reasons?

The only likely solution I can think of short of moving the `Regex` declaration closer to use is to clone the objects before use, but this seems like it could be quite slow.

For reference, here is the Worker Function that runs concurrently on 4 different threads.

```
 private void FoxFileConvWorker(ConcurrentQueue<string> queue,QueueProgressData qpd)
    {
        string[] extensions = {".fdf", ".m1", ".g"};
        while (!queue.IsEmpty)
        {
            string file;
            if (queue.TryDequeue(out file))
            {
                if (extensions.Any(extension => Path.GetExtension(file) == extension))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        _jobGraphics.Add(new Graphic(file));
                        IncrementProgress(qpd);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        ThreadSafeControlMethods.SetText(qpd.LblStatus, "Non-Fatal Error");
                        WriteLog(e, $"Creating Graphic DOM for {file}");
#if DEBUG
                        throw;
#endif
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: As far as I understand, you are not using the `Match` on different threads. Only the `Regex`. Can you show us one example of Regex in your static class ? I don't think your problem comes from the `Match`.

Comment: This constructor runs on different threads, and the `Match` is used near the bottom: `_symbols.Add(new Symbol(RegexLib.InstString.Match(Lines[instString]), 
                    RegexLib.UserdataString.Match(Lines[userdataString])));` I can add the code for the `Symbol()` if you think it would be of use. I have also attached two example regexes.

Comment: As noted, it is likely you have misdiagnosed your problem. Fact is, `Regex` should be usable across multiple threads without problem. Without a good [mcve] it's impossible to know what your problem might be. That said, the first thing you should do is add `RegexOptions.Compiled` to the constructors for the `Regex` objects. It's possible that you are corrupting the regex compilation cache (`Regex` saves the most recent compiled objects, but if you have many, there might be some concurrency issues there). Fix your question if you need more specific help than that.

Comment: What are you doing with your _symbol next ? Is it a thread safe collection ?

Comment: The `Symbol` sits in that particular `Graphic`'s `List<Symbol>` so no, it's not threadsafe, but each individual graphic is created on a single thread so it shouldn't have to be (as far as I know). To clarify; the `Graphic()` constructor isn't mutithreaded in and of itself, it is simply called from many threads concurrently for different files.

Comment: I don't know about that Graphic API, but if your list isn't thread safe, try a thread-safe one. If two thread are adding in the list in the same time, you will probably encounter some issues.

Comment: @fharreau, two threads aren't adding to the same list, as far as I can tell (see edit).

Comment: The provided samples of code can't help us because we can't see the big picture. For example, with your worker sample, I can't tell where it calls your first sample. What are exactly the issues you are running into ?

Comment: @fharreau, the top example is called from within `Graphic()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you modify your static Regex class ? If so, you can use a Factory instead of static properties:

```
static class RegexLib
{
    static Regex CreateInstString(){
    {
        return new Regex("YourRegex");
    }

    static Regex CreateUserdataString(){
    {
        return new Regex("YourOtherRegex");
    }

    [..]
}
```

This way, you regex will not be shared among threads.

You could also use some dependency injection but this means a lot of refactoring in your code.

Comment: I can modify my regex class without much issue, that seems like a fairly elegant solution. Are the performance implications significant?

Comment: @JamesHughes: Measure them. If you can't, they're probably not :)

Comment: @TomasLycken I'm just about to, was just wondering if there were any obviously heavy issues that you guys knew off the top of your head beforehand to save the time.

Comment: Did my answer actually solved your issues ? According to the discussion in the comment, that would be a surprise (a good one ;))

Comment: @JamesHughes: The thing is, even if there are performance implications (say, as a thought experiment and to make things extreme, creating a new `Regex` instance costs 100x of re-using one), we have no idea if they're significant *in your application*. If you're parsing millions of strings with the same patterns, you want to cache it. If you're using it once per web request, after going to the db three times, even the 100x speed difference isn't going to be noticable, even in your profiler.

Comment: It's fixed it mate, thanks, I changed it to a single function using an enum and a switch to return the right Regex.